# Filling background using CSS - two different colors and one overlapping another

Tags: css, linear-gradients

Can I create such fill only using CSS (without image as background) and how?

[image]

I mean - I have two divs that are filled with two colors, but I can fill them only in regular color, but I need one "overlapping" part.

Maybe I need two divs and fill them with `background-color` and the third div with "two overlapping" background colors. However, I do not know how to create this overlapping part.

Comment: i cant see the image from workplace but do you need css gradient?https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your question. You want 2 divs to overlap and have the overlapping as the overlapping color? So if you have a purple and a black div, the overlapping color should be a purple/black color?

Comment: @renathy: I hadn't added the linear-gradients tag initially as I wasn't sure if that's what you wanted. Hope you have no concerns with the tag addition now. Feel free to roll back if you have any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of-course you can do that using multiple elements and overlapping them but the easiest method is to use angled `linear-gradient` for background like in the below snippet. Making the color stop point of the first color as the start point of the second color makes the gradient output look like 2 solid colors instead of a gradual change from one to another. (**Note:** I had added a delta of 0.5% to the color start of the second color because angled gradients generally produce jagged edges and this avoids it.)

```css
.two-colors {
  height: 75px;
  width: 400px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, blue 60%, black 60.5%);
}
```

```html
<div class='two-colors'></div>
```